# Java Workflow with local text file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io

I'm new to java and Programming in general, let's say i'm building a program, this programm has several classes and a main, and i wanna to make it portable so that people who are not that in computers can click on an executable and use it. Now this program needs to work (by now it's the only solution I can think of) on a Text file which is given with the program, a text file in which people needs to fill with some text before they try to use the program, so that they "personalize" the data that will be processed at runtime. Probably it's not a good idea but i'm trying to figure it out how the all thing have to work, i have to give an empty txt, but where? how in the source code can i get a mention to the local folder  which will obviously change from one user to an other.

Sorry if it's not clear, i'm also a bit confused and English is not my primary language.
I also have other doubts about generating the final files to share with people, now i'm working on Eclipse, a command line program without a GUI can be made runnable by a simple jar file?
Thanks

Comment: To make your program portable I would look into storing it in a runnable .jar file, which is like an executable zip file which stores all your classes.  Regarding the text file have you considered making a GUI to enter the data in or alternatively use something like a JFileChooser to select the relevant text file :)

Comment: With META-INF/MANIFEST.MF containing "Main-Class: my.package.MyClass" and in a package `my.package` have a class `MyClass` with `public static void main(String[] args)` you setup a clickable, executable .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

User can pass the path to the text file in console while running the app and you can get it from the array in yours entry point:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```